# What does universal set $U$ mean in the following context?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

Suppose I read a statement somewhere that says "Let $U$ be universal set. Let $A$ and $B$ be the only sets in $U$".

I am confused as to what does this statement imply about $U$. Do we simply take $U = A \cup B$ ? Or can $U$ be something larger?

Comment: See [this](https://byjus.com/maths/universal-set/)

Comment: That page is unclear. It says that the universal set "associated" (a vague term) with $A$ and $B$ is $A \cup B$.  The OP said that the only sets *in* $U$ are $A$, $B$. The word *in* refers to membership - the only sets which are the members of $U$ are $A$ and $B$.

Comment: More context would help. Are you doing axiomatic set theory and considering a universe with only two objects?

Comment: More context please. *Did* you read that somewhere, and if so, where? Was it an exercise? What was the author writing about before that statement?

Answer (score 1):

It says, let $A$ and $B$ be the *only* sets in $U$.  So, we are taking $U = \{A, B\}$ not $A \cup B$.